# Are there many ways of incrementing a pointer in C and what's the difference here?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, indexing

I am learning C and was trying to figure out how to increment a pointer when I have this instantiation: `int A[] = {111, 222, 333};  int *q = A;` and then I'm trying to increment the pointer `q` from the zero-index of `A` to the next one.

I write two functions:

```
void incr_ptr_single ( int *p ) {
    *&p = *&p + 1;
}

void incr_ptr_double ( int **h ) {
    *h = *h + 1;
}
```

I understand that saying `void incr_ptr( int *p) { p = p+1; } inc_ptr(q);` doesn't do what I want because C's functions are "pass by value".

For now, `incr_ptr_double(&q) == A[1]` but `incr_ptr_single(q) == A[0]`. I'm wondering how to fix the `incr_ptr_single` function such that it behaves like `incr_ptr_double`.

Comment: You can pass the pointer by-reference in `incr_ptr_single`.

Comment: `*&p = *&p + 1;` is the same as `p = p + 1;`

Comment: You can also *return* the updated pointer instead of updating it in place.

Comment: Function `incr_ptr_single` doesn't have any effect outside its scope.

Comment: @mastov This question is tagged C, not C++. So there are no references

Comment: @king_nak: Oh, I see.

Comment: I'm curious why you don't just use `++q;` in the caller's code and scrap *both* functions entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to "fix" `incr_ptr_single` would be to have it return the incremented pointer as a function result:

```
int * incr_ptr_single ( int *p ) {
    return p + 1;
}
```

You could then call it as:

```
q = incr_ptr_single(q);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
q++;
```

Or if you wish to obfuscate your code so that it turns slower and far less readable:

```
int* incr_ptr (const int* p) {
  return (int*)++p;
}
```

Or alternatively

```
void incr_ptr (int** p) 
{
  (*p)++;
}
```

There are also many other ways you can make your code worse, like function-like macros.

Or if bad programming practice for some reason is not your cup of tea, just go with `q++`.